# Exclude merge_request, push to create jobs in gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

```
workflow:
   rules:
     - if : '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "Sprint-Release-Branch"'
       when: never
     - if : '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"' 
       when: never
     - when: always

stages:
 - Stage1
 - Stage2
 - Stage3
  
Task1:
  stage: Stage1
  script:
    - echo "Stage1"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.DEV\d+/'
  tags:
    - Runner

Task2:
  stage: Stage1
  script:
    - echo "Checking code standard as per "Coding Standards""
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.DEV\d+/'
  allow_failure: true
  tags:
    - Runner


Task3:
  stage: Stage2
  script:
     - echo "Stage2"
  when: manual
  tags:
    - Runner


Task4:
  stage: Stage3
  script:
     - echo "Stage3"
  when: manual
  tags:
    - Runner
```

Above is my Gitlab CI file, where i am trying

- pipeline should not add jobs when there is merge & push requests happened on "Sprint-Release-Branch"

but whenever any merge request done "feature branches" onto "Sprint-Release-Branch" jobs which are defined as "when: manual" get added in pipeline.

So in my situation, Dev team is creating different feature branch for different user-stories, and then merging those features branches onto Sprint-Release-Branch having above yml file. So multiple jobs are getting added in pipeline continuously for every merge_request which are defined with "manual" trigger

How can i make optimized my yml so that jobs having manual trigger should not get added in pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

> which are defined as "when: manual" get added in pipeline.

You have to repeat the whole logic when you overwrite it.

```
Task3:
  ...
  rules:
     - if : '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "Sprint-Release-Branch"'
       when: never
     - if : '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"' 
       when: never
     - when: manual
```

Also, it's better to use `when: on_success`, not always.

Do something like the following with yaml anchors:

```
.myrules: &myrules
  if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "Sprint-Release-Branch" || ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push")
  when: never

workflow:
   rules:
     - *myrules
     - when: on_success

Task3:
  ...
  rules:
     - *myrules
     - when: manual
```

Comment: when i am adding "- when: on_success" its giving error

Syntax is incorrect. CI configuration validated, including all configuration added with the includes keyword

workflow:rules:rule when unknown value: on_success

Comment: `when, can only be always or never when used with workflow. ` so it's not for workflow